# Kinvey OnPushReceived event is never received

Tags: push-notification, c++builder, kinvey

I have configured the Kinvey account for both Android and iOS. 
I uploaded the .p12 certificate for iOS and have created an application in Google Developer console for the GCM.

When my application logs in to Kinvey, I am getting a Token for the user. 
The application then Registers the device and I receive back a Device Token which is written to the Kinvey Users table. At this point, it is clear that the Kinvey connection is valid as I read other tables from Kinvey.

I am receiving events from the `TPushEvents` component:
`OnDeviceTokedReceived`,
`OnDeviceRegistered`.
This is occurring on both platforms: Android and iOS.

The question is why am I not getting the `OnPushReceived` event?

I log into the Kinvey Console and send a push event. It shows that the Push was sent to 3 users (2 android and 1 iOS device that are registered) but I am never getting the event on the device.
[Kinvey Console and TKinveyProvider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAjRb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not titled to give you a comment to (missing some likes) your post, so I must give you an "answer" to get som more information...

1. Have you added an eventhandler such as "TForm1::PushEvents1PushReceived" handler to check if you actually receive a push ?
2. Turn OFF your app and send a push when it is not on, you should receive a message in the notification list on your device (will not appear if your app is running).
3. Check if following settings are set

`->'Project'->'Options...'->'Entitlement List'->'Receive push notifications': true
->'Project'->'Options...'->'Uses Permissions'->'Internet': true (default)`

Comment: Didn't read your post good enough, so I think you have achieved pt 1 & 2, but pt 3... ?

Comment: void __fastcall TGrouperDM::PushEvents1PushReceived(TObject *Sender, TPushData * const AData)
 {
 //
 frmGrouper->Memo1->Lines->Add("PushReceived:");
 frmGrouper->Memo1->Lines->Add(AData->Message.Trim());
 }

Comment: 2. I have turned off app same result

Comment: 3. These are checked